# Numpy calculations not computing correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, math

Consider these lines of code:

```
    y[:,:,i,p] = np.divide(x[:,:,i,p], npq)   #divide array by constant
    orig = np.dot(y[:,:,i,p], npq)            #take previous output, and multiply by constant
    print(np.mean(x[:,:,i,p] - orig))         #print mean. should be 0
```

The expected output of these calculations should be 0. Rather, i'm getting the following:

```
...
0.0
-1.81671383445
-0.0719097733101
-0.102587446807
...
```

What am I doing wrong? I've tried converting all the numbers to integers rather than floating points, and the errors persist.

**EDIT**
np.multiply does not fix the problem.
I wrote my own multiplication code. It just runs through the array, and it works perfectly, albeit much slower.

Comment: It's hard to help you without knowing the original values of the arrays.

Comment: `dot` != multiplication by constant.

Comment: Basically, you decided not to read the docs/experiment and just assumed what `dot` would do (incorrectly). Use `multiply` instead.

Comment: When `npq` is a scalar, `np.dot(y, npq)` *is* the same as `np.multiply(y, npq)`.  I don't recommend using `dot` with a scalar, because it will confuse anyone who reads the code, and it is much slower.  However, it is not the cause of the problem described in the question.

Comment: I'm not convinced `npq` was ever a scalar constant.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is most likely the loss of precision that occurs with finite precision floating point numbers.

If `npq` is a scalar, then `np.dot(y[:,:,i,p], npq)` will give the same result as `np.multiply(y[:,:,i,p], npq)`.  So your code would print 0.0, if the floating point calculations were done with infinite precision.  Of course, they are not; the default floating point data type is `np.float64`, so there can be loss of precision in arithmetic calculations.  I suspect this is why the values that are printed are not 0.0.

For example,

```
In [78]: npq = 3

In [79]: np.random.seed(123)

In [80]: x = 1e20*np.random.randn(100, 100)

In [81]: y = np.divide(x, npq)

In [82]: orig = np.dot(y, npq)
```

If we had infinite precision, this result would be 0:

```
In [83]: np.mean(x - orig)
Out[83]: -5.2468000000000004
```

The largest error in the "round trip" calculation is:

```
In [84]: np.max(np.abs(x - orig))
Out[84]: 32768.0
```

Using `np.multiply(y, npq)` instead of `np.dot(y, npq)` gives exactly the result result:

```
In [85]: xx = np.multiply(y, npq)

In [86]: np.max(np.abs(x - xx))
Out[86]: 32768.0
```

Comment: Upvoted, since this actually does answer the question.

Comment: So that's what I thought too, and I did similar computations. I solved the problem by writing my own multiplication code rather than using anything predefined. Significantly slower, it's terrible, but now it's accurate.